# Symfony with Polymer

Tags: symfony, twig, polymer

I would like to use Polymer in my Symfony project. Looks good but Polymer has similar syntax as Twig so I tried to find the solution.

I found Polyphonic Polymer Bundle by headzoo (http://www.polyphonic-symfony.org/en/latest/) but as I see on GitHub latest commit made 11 months ago and on website placed attention like: "This bundle is no where near production ready. Use at your own risk."

Maybe somebody already used Polymer with Symfony and Twig and can share the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's about the double curlies, you could just reconfigure twig to use something else. [http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax). Or if all fails, use [`verbatim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks Yoshi, your comment is very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! If you get it to work, you might want to share your solution (even accept it as the answer) to help future visitors.